# Intersect a list with column pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark df like this:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
|            id|                recs|
+--------------+--------------------+
|     420281136|[531698003, 81262...|
|     801646419|[685057033, 11542...|
|     920475166|[344077868, 99389...|
|     577242054|[242471215, 99876...|
|     858082577|[910361558, 75957...|
+--------------+--------------------+

[('id', 'string'), ('recs', 'array<string>')]
```

Now I have list with 4k elements:

```
a:

['100075010',
 '100755706',
 '1008039072',
 '1010520008',
 '101081875',
 '101418337',
 '101496347',
 '10153658',
 '1017744620',
 '1021412485'...]
```

Now I want to create another column with intersection of list `a and recs` column.

Here's what I tried:

```
def column_array_intersect(col_name):
    return f.udf(lambda arr: f.array_intersect(col_name, arr), ArrayType(StringType()))

df = df.withColumn('intersect', column_array_intersect("recs")(f.array(a)))
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o212.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`100075010`' given input columns: [anchor_item_id, recs];;
'Project [anchor_item_id#0, recs#156, <lambda>(array('100075010, '100755706, '1008039072, '1010520008, '101081875, '101418337, '101496347, '10153658, '1017744620, '1021412485, '1021845009, '102191240, '10239093, '102617377, '10265400, '10293250, '10295721, '102989529, '10309597, '10311990, '10312907, '10314212, '10314212, '10321251, ... 508253 more fields)) AS intersect#174]
+- Project [anchor_item_id#0, recs#156]
   +- Project [anchor_item_id#0, model#1, rec_item_info_list#2, reco_item_category_set#3, category#4, item_name#5, brand#6, primary_shelf_value#7, price#8, num_appr_reviews#9, avg_overall_rating#10, prod_type#11, rec_item_info_list#2.item_id AS recs#156]
      +- Relation[id#0,model#1,rec_item_info_list#2,reco_item_category_set#3,category#4,item_name#5,brand#6,primary_shelf_value#7,price#8,num_appr_reviews#9,avg_overall_rating#10,prod_type#11] parquet
```

Here I'm seeing the column which I have already removed from df with select statement.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('a_list', f.array(*[f.lit(element) for element in a]))
    .withColumn('intersection', f.array_intersect(f.col('recs', 'a_list')))
    .drop('a_list')
)
```